# Can flair page be improved by showing that styles can apply to the combined profile?

Tags: feature-request, flair, combined-flair

Right now, it talks about styles on the individual flair but not the group flair.

I checked by tring it out and the flair style *can* be used on the group profile too.

So underneath the "… and for the combined Stack Exchange flair:" and the html code, it might say:

"You can also apply the clean, dark and hotdog styles to the combined profile."

Also when it says add the parameter to the end of the URL it might be a good idea to say "e.g. if the URL contains "image.jpg" make that "image.jps?theme=dark", keeping the rest of the code the same.

Finally for the combined profile it might (but not really sure) be a good idea, that with the above changes, add the additional styled examples, similar to the way they are shown above for the individual flair.

Comment: We'll probably table this for just a bit...we're working (for other reasons) on serving flair over SSL, which may necessitate a few moves behind the scenes and some UI updates in itself (we won't break existing uses of course).

Comment: I'd rather have custom colors. Please add the optional URL parameters `bgcolor`, `bordercolor`, and `textcolor`. :D